# Match.Regex syntax

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that can be either

```
"MyName (ctid 5555)"
```

or

```
"OtherName (id 555-5555-5555-555)"
```

I tried to write a regex to fetch `ctid` or `id`, like so:

```
"(?<=ctid=).+(?=))"
```

[Checking here](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx) gave 0 results.

What's wrong with my syntax?

Comment: You should also include the expected output of the regex. Expecting people to know the desired output based on broken input is a bit unfair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that a ctid is always 4 digits, and an id is always 3-4-4-3 digits, and that either way it is enclosed in round brackets, I would do:

```
\((?:ctid (?<ctid>\d{4})|id (?<id>\d{3}-\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{3}))\)
```

This adds named groups and does validity checking at the same time. For example, you can use `match.Groups['ctid'].value` to get the ctid value, or `['id']` to get the id value. Because there is validity checking, you'll never get (what I am assuming is) an invalid id like "(id 123)" (since it doesn't have the 3-4-4-3 pattern).

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern: `(?<=\((?:ctid|id)\s).+?(?=\))`

It uses a look-behind to check for "ctid" or "id" followed by whitespace, then it matches any content up till the closing parenthesis.

```
string[] inputs = { "MyName (ctid 5555)", "OtherName (id 555-5555-5555-555)" };
string pattern = @"(?<=\((?:ctid|id)\s).+?(?=\))";

foreach (var input in inputs)
{
    var result = Regex.Match(input, pattern).Value;
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

If you clarify your question a better solution might exist. If you care to know whether the value was a "ctid" or an "id" then named capture groups could be used.

Comment: i want to know whether the value was a "ctid" or an "id" . How to use named capture groups?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example, I am assuming you require a regex to explicitally match

```
try
{
    var idRegEx = "^.*?\s\(id\s(\d{3}-\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{3})\)$";
    var ctIdRegex = "^.*?\s\(ctid\s(\d{4})\)$";

    var idMatch = Regex.Replace(textToTest, idRegEx, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;
    var ctIdMatch = Regex.Replace(textToTest, ctIdRegex , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;
}
catch(ArgumentException)
{
   // Regex is wrong
}
catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
{
   // No match found on one or the other
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're looking for 'ctid=' and the string has 'ctid '.  You'll also need to escape the parenthesis in the lookahead (change `')`' to `'\)'`.

Comment: @EladBenda I didn't escape the text in SO, so it didn't display the `\`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want *exactly*

```
(?:(ct)?id)\s(.+?)\)
```

But this regex worked for me at

http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

you just need to grab the 2nd group though...

If you don't really want the look around regex, then

`\((ct)?id\s(.+?)\)`

might do it as well (and is more readable for regex beginners)